# Send Pillow image on Discord without saving the image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   image = Image.open('background.png')
   font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size=35)
   draw.text((0, 0), f"Example", fill="white", font=font)

   draw.save("image.png")
   await ctx.send(File=discord.File("image.png"))
```

How would I go about sending the image created with `Pillow.py` without having to save the image first. I have tried to search through Stack Overflow to find a working response to this, however I did not find any working method. Any help is appreciated!
Previously I tried using IO to solve this, but it just ends up sending empty files.

Comment: You convert the image to base64 and then read it with the fpio reader

Comment: See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fp#discord.File.fp

Comment: @Saddy Do you mean like this?
        ```my_string = base64.b64encode(image.tobytes())
        file = discord.File(fp=my_string, filename="skills.png")
        await ctx.send(file=file)```

Comment: yeah like that. My version is slightly different but if it works it works

Comment: @Saddy this one does not work, hehe. Could you post your version and I can test that out? (Kinda more wondering if I was on the right track)

Comment: I'd suggest looking into StringIO and BytesIO to find whichever suites you best. read more in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: discord.File(fp=BytesIO(x)) where x is an object created by fp.read() on a File

Comment: it says to use BytesIO in [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#file), you can create BytesIO from image bytes `BytesIO(image.tobytes())`

Comment: When I write ```x = io.BytesIO(image.tobytes())
        file = discord.File(fp=x)
        await ctx.send(file=file)``` a file with no filetype and 2.65 MB size gets sent. No image, did I write something wrong or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: how to save image to bytesio
```with io.BytesIO() as output:\n
    image.save(output, format=[...])```, will have to specify format

Comment: @DelphiX Just sends an empty file

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a1c7c422fdffea0dbc8cedae166f1013 ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
                    image.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
                    image_binary.seek(0)
                    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='image.png'))
```

With the usage of seek it works out.