# Random Color as a picture discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i want to get a color and not a number from the bot

My Code:

```
def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)

    rgbl = [r, g, b]
    return tuple(rgbl)

...
```

```
        if p_message == "rcolor":
            return "A random color is: " + str(random_color())
```

For example:

*The Bot* - A random color is: (178, 207, 184)

But i want a small picture like that:

[Dyno Bot Command: `/color`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kiZl.png)

Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 1):

You are currently only creating values for red, green and blue and outputting these as text via the bot. To actually send a image with the color, that image first has to be created. as `Hazzu` pointed out in their Answer, you can use the library [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for that. They have however not added any examples of how you can combine it with discord.

For this to work, you need to install Pillow using `pip install Pillow`.

To create the image, you can simply create the following function:

```py
from PIL import Image

def generate_color_image(color):
    # Create a Image with size 100x100 colored in the provided color. 
    return Image.new(mode = "RGB", size= (100, 100), color)
```

and sending the image to discord can be done using the code as described in [this answer in a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63210850/10568035):

```
def send_random_color(ctx):
    # Create a image using the color as generated in the questions random_color() function.
    image = generate_color_image(random_color())

    # Create a buffer, save the image in that buffer and send it as a file.
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        image.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='color.png'))
```

This function has to be called with the commands context (`ctx`). It will send a plain image, not an embed like the example you sent shows. For that you need to look at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) for the `Embed` type and extend the example accordingly. - I cannot currently write a example for that.

Please note that I couldn't test this code - It might contain slight mistakes.